# Xamarin NavigationView menu item customization

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fonts, navigationview

Hi I use C# and Xamarin to develop my new application and ran into many problems using this platform. Is it possible to customize menu items inside NavigationView using xamarin? all I found are the [valid properties for the menu items](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).
But what if instead of this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/itemOne"
      android:title="Go to page one" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/itemTwo"
      android:title="Go to page two" />
</menu>
```

I want to do this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView></TextView>
    <Button></Button>
    <SomeOtherControlHere></SomeOtherControlHere>
</menu>
```

Is it possible using xamarin? What are my other options?

Aside from that I found that Xamarin API's are very restrictive, for example you cant use custom ttf fonts directly inside xml to set the fonts for menu items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
          android:id="@+id/itemOne"
          android:title="Go to page one" 
          android:fontFamily="MyCustomFontName Or MyPathToFonts" /> <-- NOT VALID
</menu>
```

Also if I apply style for an entire menu items container it is also not possible to use custom fonts, the only fonts we can use is the built in fonts...

Even if I get reference inside my Activity to an individual menu item (IMenuItem), there is no property or function to set font family.

Comment: How do you use NavigationView? Can you show this part of your axml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to define a more complex NavigationView. Just put the child controls inside the NavigationView-Tag. For example, this is how I use the NavigationView to implement a footer. There are no restrictions to the child controls so you can you Buttons etc. as well:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    local:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    local:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    local:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_spacer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_small"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

To change the TextSize of the items for example, you have to define an own style:

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
   <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
   <!-- more properties -->
</style>
```

Then assign it to your NavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle">
   <!-- ... -->
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I format the Navigation Menu Item which starts by icon, then menu text and the last one is number. It look like the one in gmail app.

OnCreate

```
navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.wnl_nav_view);

            //Add customize menu item style
            IMenu menuNav = navigationView.Menu;
            View view = View.Inflate(this, Resource.Layout._drawerMenuItemTemplate, null);
            IMenuItem logoutItem = menuNav.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_mail);
            MenuItemCompat.SetActionView(logoutItem, view);
            TextView txtNewNumber = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNewNumber);
```

_drawerMenuItemTemplate.axml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:text="3/30"
        android:id="@+id/txtNewNumber"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:fontFamily="@string/abc_font_family_display_2_material"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```